# Windows Defender constantly fills and empties all available memory

Tags: windows-11, windows-defender

For some reason my Windows Defender takes up unusual amounts of memory. When starting it constantly eats 5.6 GB sometimes cleaning up but soon taking it up again. When I start Webstorm for some reason and start my web project with `ng serve` it suddenly starts to go mad by constantly eating up almost all my memory and dropping it. Constantly without end until I restart.

My PC is completely useless as Windows starts to freeze and slow down. See this memory timeline from Task Manager:

[image]

When I try to open Windows Defender the window freezes and stops responding instantly. Never showing up. The process using up all memory is "**Windows Defender -> MicrosoftSecurityApp.exe**"

I already tried using `sfc /scannow` and `dism` with `/RestoreHealth`. Nothing helped so far. Anyone got an idea how to stop this madness?

Comment: Ok I found out that it was not the Windows security itself but the Microsoft Defender app which seems to be some unnecessary tool for cross-device security. Just uninstalled it and the problem was luckily gone.

Comment: Check that you still have an active, working anti-malware suite. Defender **does** slow things for a few minutes after startup, but should not be a problem after 10 minutes or so.